# Duplicating layout with PyQGIS 3

Tags: print-composer, pyqgis-3, pyqt5, duplication, layout-manager

I want a script in PyQGIS 3. For example:

This code creates a layout **"2019_A4"** and adds Layout Manager. I need a code to make the same in QGIS 3 using the `QgsLayoutManager` with the `duplicateLayout` method.

Here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsLayoutManager.html

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.core import *

# A Project, Manager, & PrintLayout Classes
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()

# layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout = manager.layoutByName("2019_A4")

#layout.initializeDefaults()
#layout.setName('2019_A')
manager.addLayout(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

With just this line of code, it's working fine for me :

```
layout_bis = manager.duplicateLayout(layout, '2019_A_bis')
```